# How to add mouse click event on Push pins in Bing map metro app using C# and Xml?

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, bing-maps

I have a multiple dynamic push pins on bing map. I want to add a mouse click event on these push pin. Tell me how can i do it. I am working in windows store app using C# and XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are adding pushpins programmatically, add common event handler `Tapped` to each pushpin. When pushpin is tapped it will be called and from `sender` object you can differentiate each push pin and do whatever you like.

```
//Suppose I have PushpinsCollection which is list of MyPushpin class. PushpinsCollection is generated dynamically
public class MyPushpin
{
    public int PinID { get; set; }
    public Pushpin Pin { get; set; }
    public Location PinLocation { get; set; }
}

//run foreach loop do add event hanlder and add to map
//Here MyMap is Bing Map control
foreach(var pushpin in PushpinsCollection)
{
    var _pin = pushpin.Pin;
    _pin.Tapped += Pushpin_Tapped
    MapLayer.SetPosition(_pin, PinLocation);
    MyMap.Children.Add(_pin);
}

private void Pushpin_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var TappedPin = (Pushpin)sender;
    //TODO: do whatever opetraion you want to with TappedPin
}
```